# I need for expert advice for my android Application Project

Tags: android

It is my first time for me to create android app
I tried to do my best effort on it but I see that it is slow when moving from activity to an other.
I need someone to see the code and guide me for the best.
so please if you have some time to visit my gibhub code and tell me what i must to do to be faster?
here is the link of gibhub: https://github.com/strikerh/IslamicTimeManager

Thank you :)

Comment: We are not here to review your project. If you have troubles with specific code post it here and we can look at it.

Comment: Wrong forum. Take a look at [codereview.stackexchange.com](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow, please take a look at the tour: https://stackoverflow.com/tour . Your question appears to be off topic to the stackoverflow questions format, please come back with a specific problem, showing what you have attempted and try to specify exactly what the issue is.

Answer (score 0):

If you want switch views faster, try to use Fragments instead Activities. There you can reed more about fragments: https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html